# Why merge-with is used instead of simple 'merge' in Ring, Clojure?

Tags: clojure, ring

I'm very new to Clojure and learning Clojure by reading 
good open source code. So I choose Ring and starting to read 
the code but got stuck in assoc-query-params function.
(which is located in [ring.middleware/params.clj](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/params.clj#L24))

And I could not understand why "merge-with" is used.
Can anybody help me to understand this code snippet?

```
(defn- assoc-query-params
  "Parse and assoc parameters from the query string with the request."
  [request encoding]

  ; I think (merge request (some-form)) is enough
  ; but the author used merge-with with merge function.

  (merge-with merge request
    (if-let [query-string (:query-string request)]
      (let [params (parse-params query-string encoding)]
        {:query-params params, :params params})
      {:query-params {}, :params {}})))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's the description](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/merge) of the `merge` function: reworded it says that if a key is met more than once than value in the latest map will be selected. In the example that you posted that would mean that values of `:query-params` `:params` will be taken as is from the tail of the function instead of combining them with what's in the request.

Let's look at the example:

```
(def m {:a {:a-key1 "value1"} :b {:b-key1 "value3"} :c {}})
(def m2 {:a {:a-key2 "value2"} :b {}})

(merge m m2)
;-> {:a {:a-key2 "value2"}, :b {}, :c {}}

(merge-with merge m m2)
;-> {:a {:a-key1 "value1", :a-key2 "value2"}, :b {:b-key1 "value3"} :c {}}
```

So `(merge-with merge ...)` construct gives us a way to merge maps in the map. You can look at it this way: merge-with will group all key/value pairs by the key (`:a` `:b` `:c` in our example) and apply merge to their values.

```
{:a (merge {:a-key1 "value1"} {:a-key2 "value2"}) 
 :b (merge {:b-key1 "value3"} {})
 :c (merge {})}
```

Having handled that I think that the original intention of the `assoc-query-params` author is to extend `:query-params` and `:params` instead of completely replacing them.